# MediaWiki User Action Logging

Tags: logging, mediawiki

Is there a way in a default MediaWiki installation to tell the following:

1. When a user has logged in or out of the system 
   I've found this extension for future use http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StalkerLog
2. To see which pages a user has viewed/reviewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Special:Log` page lists all special actions (Move, Block, Patrol, etc...) and can be viewed by user. Similarly, the `Special:Contributions` page lists all edits by user/IP. I'm not aware of any way of getting the list of user log on/off times or even the last log on time in the default installation of MediaWiki.

If looking at extensions there are likely a few existing options or making your own. Just a quick search revealed [LastLoginTime](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:LastLoginTime), [SpecialLastUserLoginEx](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SpecialLastUserLoginEx), and [UserLoginLog](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UserLoginLog). How well these work or not is another matter.